# How do I return an output for lambda expression to be the actual date in string format

Tags: python

```
my_date = input('Please enter your start date with format year/month/day: ')
print(f'You entered {my_date}')

split_my_date = my_date.split("/") 

a = int(split_my_date[0]) # Year
b = int(split_my_date[1]) # Month
c = int(split_my_date[2]) # Day

s_my_date = str(lambda r_s_my_date : date(a,b,c) + timedelta(days=100))
#e_my_date = str(lambda r_e_my_date : date(a,b,c) - timedelta(days=100))

print(s_my_date)
type(s_my_date)
```

Hi, I'm a noob actually. What I'm trying to accomplish is to print s_my_date and output my_date + 100 days. For example if I input "2022/3/1" as my_date, its output will be s_my_date = 2022/3/1 plus 100 days but I need this output to be a string. Unfortunately whenever I print(s_my_date) it just returns

```
<function <lambda> at 0x7f66f2a12790>
```

I also tried to read some comments but can't really wrap my head around it yet so taking my chances to post my actual work. Thank you!

Comment: You can [convert a string into datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime): `my_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(my_date, "%Y/%m/%d")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is to pass the year, month and date as parameters to your lambda function and return the date + 100 days.

In that case, it should be like this,

```
s_my_date = lambda a, b, c : str(date(a,b,c) + timedelta(days=100))
```

`a`, `b` and `c` are your parameters, which will be used in the function.

What comes after the colon is what is going to be returned by your function. So, you need to convert your parameters to a date: `date(a,b,c)`, add the 100 days: `date(a,b,c) + timedelta(days=100)` and then convert it to a string: `str(date(a,b,c) + timedelta(days=100))`.

This does not make sense either because it's like we are trying to convert the function itself into a string,
str(lambda a, b, c : date(a,b,c) + timedelta(days=100))

I am not entirely sure what `r_s_my_date` is, but maybe you were trying to name your function?

Lambda functions are anonymous functions and they will not be named.

Now, this function is stored in the variable `s_my_date`. So, now you have to call it,

```
print(s_my_date(a, b, c))
```

Here, you are passing in your variables which are also called `a`, `b` and `c`.

You can learn more about anonymous (lambda) functions here,
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp

Comment: If my solution solved your problem, I would really appreciate it if you can click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.

Comment: Hello Minura, I appreciate this. Yes you are right, I was trying to assign the lambda function to r_s_my_date as I wanted to retrieve the output of that function. Thank you for advising me that "Lambda functions are anonymous functions and they will not be named."